# How to read and import data from Excel to database using EEPLUS

Tags: c#

I want to read data from excel using EEPLUS in C#. Who can teach me or share the link to teach it? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (offsite resource recommendation questions are expressly off-topic, per guidelines). If there's a specific question you have, please edit your question to give those details.

Answer (score -1):

It is really easy to use, just read through the [GetStarted of their GitHub](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started).

Example:

```
//Open the workbook (or create it if it doesn't exist)
var fi=new FileInfo(@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx")
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
       //Get the Worksheet created in the previous codesample. 
       var ws=p.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];
       Set the cell value using row and column.
       ws.Cells[2, 1].Value = "This is cell A2. It is set to bolds";
       //The style object is used to access most cells formatting and styles.
       ws.Cells[2, 1].Style.Font.Bold=true;
       //Save and close the package.
       p.Save();
    }
```

Comment: You lifted this entire code block directly from the getting-started page that you pointed to. Please don't just copy-paste from a tutorial. As I mentioned under the question, it's off-topic (tutorial recommendation). And this is a resource the op should be able to find, given that it's part of the repo itself. That said: you could have posted the getting-started link under the question, as a comment, not as an answer (you have enough rep to do so).